# How can I detect that a View was load in the tabBarController.moreNavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to redraw the UINavigation Bar when I load a View from the moreNavigationController. How can I detect that a view has been loaded by the tabBarController.moreNavigationController?

Answer (score 0):

The view controller responsible for the view will get a `viewDidLoad` callback. If you want to know when a navigation pushes/pops view controllers you can set a delegate to the navigation controller and implement the following methods

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: No, I only want to difference between the Views that had been loaded by pressing a tab bar button item and the views that had been loaded by selecting an element in the tab bar controller more list.